# How can I use observer design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to use the Observer design pattern for a school project, but I'm having problems with it. 
I have a timer and an int which decrements itself, I want to make an observer so when the int becomes 0, a jdialog pops up.

Here is my code:

```
 public class Joc extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
 javax.swing.Timer t1;
 int time=0,
 MyObservator obs = new MyObservator();

   public Joc()
   { ... // constructor stuff
    t1=new javax.swing.Timer(1000, (ActionListener) this);
    t1.start();}

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if(time>0) {time--;}
   else {}
   }
```

// My observator class

```
public class MyObservator implements Observer{
Joc joc;
MyJDialog dialog;

 @Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    if(joc.time==0)
    {dialog.setVisible(true);}
}
```

}

I didn't understand how to use the observer, how can I make add the observer and how can I make it function?

Comment: I posted a simple example with some explanation, let me know if you have any questions, I would be glad to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the observer pattern you start with a basic interface for an observer.  The observers notify method will be called by some other class when a particular event occurs.

```
public interface IObserver {

    public void notify(int i);
}
```

Now the interface needs an implementation:

```
public class Observer implements IObserver {

    @Override
    public void notify(int i) {
        if(i % 1000 == 0){
            System.out.println("One thousand iterations elapsed.");
        }
    }

}
```

The observable needs something to observe.  So a class is created that contains a list of `IObservers`.  Notice that `IObserver`s can be added to the list contained by the `Observable`.  If desired, the `addObserver` method can be specified in an interface which is then implemented by `Observable`.  Also notice that the `Observable` class calls the `notify` method when a particular event occurs.  The `IObserver` is notified of these events and can perform any action when they occur.  In our example, if the `int` is 1000 we print some text to the console.

```
public class Observable {

    private List<IObserver> observers = new ArrayList<IObserver>();

    public void addObserver(IObserver observer){
        this.observers.add(observer);
    }

    public void execute(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            for(IObserver observer: observers){
                observer.notify(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In a program we register instances implementing `IObserver` with the `Observable` instance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable observable = new Observable();
    observable.addObserver(new Observer());
    observable.execute();
}
```

In your example, the `Joc` class is equivalent to the `Obserable` class.  It should contain a list of `Observer`s and notify them when a particular event occurs via the `update` method.