# How to notify all children object from parent object?

Tags: java, oop

Lets say I have a Parent Object, and I have several Children objects. 
If one children does some special action, I want to notify all other childrens about it. 
How should I do it? 
Should I store all children in some array or are there any other more convenient approaches?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742055/how-can-i-use-observer-design-pattern/16742309#16742309

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case Parent object is `Observable` and children objects is `Observers`

Object which does some special action must implement `Observable` interface:

```
public interface Observable {
    void addObserver(Observer o);
    void removebserver(Observer o);
    void notifyObservers();
}
```

Concrete `Observable` class must also have array of observers(here children objects).
So children objects must implement simple Observer interface.

```
public interface Observer {
    void update(/*data which you need to update in your children objects*/);
}
```

Later you need to register all your children objects to array of `Observers` in parent object using `Observable.addObserver(Observer o);` method. And after you can send them information using `Observable.notifyObservers()` method.

Also look it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)!

Comment: what about the contrary?  I there any pattern to notify  parent  about children property changes ?

Answer (score 2):

User observer pattern, learn more about it from here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern